# proj4js with geocentric CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, epsg, proj4js

I am developing a little web app to transform coordinates between CRSs. To do that I am using proj4js, but I notice that proj4js can't work with geocentric CRSs.

Is there another tool similar to proj4 to work with geocentric CRSs, or I have to code the formulas between geocentric-geographic coordinates. Once I have geographic coordinates I use proj4js to obtain projected coordinates.

Comment: Where do you notice this?

Comment: For example. If you define the CRS with code EPSG:4936 as a string and reference using the proj4.defs method:

proj4.defs('EPSG:4936', +proj=geocent +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs);

"Uncaught EPSG:4936" message is launched.

Comment: I've tried various systems but every time there is +proj=geocent it fails. On github page there is an issue https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/195 which suggests a workaround but I wasn't able to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

[cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html) is a good tool for this. Look at the as_geodetic and as_geocentric functions and associated classes in their [CRS docs](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/index.html). It uses proj4 under the hood but is better about dealing with Cartesian 3d.

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of proj4.js works well.

```
var proj4 = require('proj4');
proj4.version;
// '2.7.5'

var geoCentric = "+proj=geocent +datum=WGS84";

// (Long,lat,h) to geocentric (x,y,z)
var xyz = proj4('WGS84', geoCentric, [100, 13, 10]);
console.log(xyz);
// [ -1079348.2174506688, 6121287.922664762, 1425405.2088229598 ]

// Reverse computation check
proj4(geoCentric, 'WGS84', xyz);
// [ 100, 13.000000000000004, 9.999999998137355 ]
```